# Spawn console window without locking application

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to spawn a console window to run another executable from my application based on some data selected by the user. It's a pretty simple setup right now.

```
std::string command;
{
    command += "\"" + INSTALL_DIR + "export.exe\"";
    command += " -id " +  processID;
}
system(command.c_str());
```

The problem is the export could take up to an hour or more and I don't want to lock up the application. I have seen mention that using "&" at the end of your command would accomplish this (like: "c:\some\path\export.exe -id 19998 &") but it's not working for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding & only works on *nix systems.

Comment: and not even in system command, bash interprets &.

Comment: I would use [CreateProcess](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The problem is the export could take up to an hour or more and I don't want to lock up the application.

[`system()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) calls are executed synchronously and block the calling thread until finished.

Look for [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) to interact with the winapi directly, or use [`fork()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/POSIX_Reference/unistd.h/fork) and some function from the [`exec()`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/POSIX_Reference/unistd.h/exec) family to *spawn* an asynchronously running child process.

---

Another (portable) solution is to use a separate [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) in your application, that issues the `system()` call:

```
std::string command;
command += "\"" + INSTALL_DIR + "export.exe\"";
command += " -id " +  processID;

std::thread t([](const std::string& command){
        system(command.c_str());
    }, command);
std::cout << "main thread" << std::endl;
```

But you need to at least join that thread before your application exits:

```
t.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

& works within the shell (command prompt). What you should do is to create a new thread using `CreateThread` or if you use C++11 `std::thread`, and call the new command from there. I would recommend not to use system command though: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/